# MacOS 10.14 Mojave login hangs with black screen and progress bar after password is accepted

Tags: big-sur, login

After upgrading to 10.14 (Big Sur), on my Macbook Pro (2017) I select my account icon and enter my password, and it starts to log me in. After a few seconds, though, it goes to a black screen with apple logo and a progress bar. The progress bar, well, it progresses for a bit and then stops indefinitely (I let it run for 12 hours at one point).

To try to debug, I start the MacBook in verbose mode by holding command-v while powering on. I select my account icon and enter password, and many many pages of verbose output scroll past, but then at some point it goes to the same black screen with progress bar.

Last two messages are (approximately)

```
launchd domain user exiting bootstrap mode
performFormatChange 
  enable?SDInterface en5 returning 0x0
  configureIPv6 en5 ipv6 disable returning 0x0
  enable?SDInterace en5 returning 0x0
  configure IPv6 en5 ipv6 enable returning 0x0
```

I tried disabling networking by using rescue mode to mount the FileVault-enabled volume to edit /.../Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist and I think that was successful but en5 doesn't appear in that file so I'm thinking it's some MacOS special interface used during login. Anyway, the problem persists.

I tried with no physical or wifi network available.

I tried on two unrelated wifi networks.

I tried using FirstAid on the volume in question in rescue mode.

The same behavior occurs for both domain-register user accounts and for local user accounts.

Is there any way I can figure out what it's trying to do during this progress bar time?

Comment: When you boot in verbose mode, can you see many messages with "..too many corpses..." etc?  Have you try a Safe boot (push shift key at boot)?

Comment: I don't see any "too many corpses" but I'm going off a video of the screen so it would be easy to miss.

Safe Boot is not available in Mojave, apparently